# Google Map functionality not working on device

Tags: ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I'm working with Intel XDK and Ionic as framework.

I'm trying to use Google Maps. It functions when I load the APK into the emulator, but not on a real device. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have provided no information regarding this, so it's unlikely this will be solved.

Comment: i am using intel xdk google map media (only drag and drop that media there is no code written any where )

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/04985wgy4jbzwubxag1luqzrg23gf0vs   this is my whole project please help me

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much because I don't know these things. :(